# How to subtract 1 year from a date object in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a date object as follows:

```
'2013-01'

'2013-02'

...
```

How to subtract 1 year from 2013 while keeping the month unchanged, for example

```
'2012-01'

'2012-02'

...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done by converting to `yearmon` class and then subtract 1

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(str1) - 1, '%Y-%m')
#[1] "2012-01" "2012-02"
```

Similarly, for subtracting a month, use `1/12`

```
format(as.yearmon(str1) - 1/12, '%Y-%m')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('2013-01', '2013-02')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check with `as.POSIXlt`

```
s=as.POSIXlt(paste0(str1,'-01'))
s$year=s$year-1
format(s,'%Y-%m')
[1] "2012-01" "2012-02"
```